# swipe android two listview selected value on button click

Tags: android, listview

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        pos = position;
        spItem1 = (listView1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        from_value_text.setText(spItem1);
        onCheckValueListener();
    }
});
```

Comment: provide more details on your problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification